# Axis 2 WS-Interoperability Basic Profile 1.1

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

Can anyone point me towards an example of how to configure an Axis 2 web service so it is WS-Interoperability Basic Profile 1.1 compliant?

Comment: This is the case by default, I believe

Answer (score 1):

I agree to skaffman, axis2 is compliant by default.

At least it claims to be... ;)

cmp. [list of compliant WS-Frameworks from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-I_Basic_Profile)